# OnClick not accepting a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to create a button that, when clicked, will change a boolean state from false to true and then open a DialogBox. I created a function to change the state from false to true however I get the following error.

"openDialog is not a function"

Here is the code for the function and the dialog I am trying to use it respectfully:

```
  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
    });
  };


<Dialog
   className="MenuOption"
   primaryText="Open"
   onClick={() => 
     openDialog()
   }
  />
```

As you can see they are very simple> I've also found other examples where the OnCLick actually work
I don't really understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Change to `this.openDialog()`

Comment: or even `onClick={this.openDialog}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this code exists in the render function and

I believe there must have curly braces if the callback is having multiple lines. Or else it has to be in one line

```
<Dialog
   className="MenuOption"
   primaryText="Open"
   onClick={() => {
     openDialog()
   }}
/>
```

Or

```
<Dialog
   className="MenuOption"
   primaryText="Open"
   onClick={() => {
     openDialog()
   }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. Like Jaromanda X mentioned in the comment, `openDialog` doesn't exist since it is `this.openDialog`, so it should be `onClick={() => this.openDialog()}`. But you don't even need that extra wrapper function, you can assign it directly: `onClick={this.openDialog}`
2. It might be just in the example but you've forgot the "render" method, it should be:

   ```
   openDialog = () => {
       this.setState({
         modalOpen: true,
       });
   };

   render() {
    return (
     <Dialog
       className="MenuOption"
       primaryText="Open"
       onClick={this.openDialog}
      />);
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `openDialog()` with `this.openDialog()`.

EDIT:
In response to your comment...

In your constructor, you'll need to bind `this` to the function in which you are using `this.setState()` so that `this` (in openDialog) points to your component and not to the function where you are setting the state.  Try this along with the first answer.

```
// in component constructor
this.openDialog = this.openDialog.bind(this)
```

Comment: it didn't work, but it is my fault because i suppose the question is incomplete. ill update it in a bit

Comment: i edited the answer... try that and see if it helps.

Comment: do i have to use this as well when i am trying to pass the function to another component/class as well?

Comment: ' pass the function to another component/class as well' - can you clarify?